# Django admin: can't adapt type 'decimal.Decimal'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm getting the exception:
"can't adapt type 'decimal.Decimal'" in Django Admin when saving the TestType model below

I can't replicate the same issue on MacOs, Windows 10 and Linux (in my dev environment), but the issue occurs at the clients'. The problem starts **randomly**, but once it happens it doesn't stop even after a restart of the client machine

I'm using the following setup:
Python 3.9.5
Django 3.2.2
psycopg2
Postgres 12.6
Apache for Windows

I'm using a simple Django model which used to work perfectly in Django admin.

```
class TestType(SortableMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data_type = models.IntegerField(null=True, choices=[(datatype.value, datatype.name) for datatype in TestDataType])
    min_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    max_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    test_template = models.ManyToManyField(TestTemplate, blank=True, default=None)
```

and in *settings.py*

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': db_name,
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': db_password,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Any clue on what might be the problem?

Comment: Why `default=None`? Use `default=Decimal('0.00')` or **remove** default. Your field is `nullable`.

Comment: Please add the complete error message from the traceback to your question.